# using two USB headphones simultaneously

Tags: usb, headphones

Using Windows 7, on an older Dell, I want to be able to use two sets of USB headsets simultaneously for watching Hulu/etc. for me and a friend without waking up my roommate. Can I just put the second set into a spare USB or is there such a thing as a USB "splitter"?

Comment: You could probably use the onboard sound card, and a 3.5 mm headphone out splitter to do what you want to do. Its a much more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, using a USB device, will turn your headset into an audio device, and in Windows or any OS for the fact, you can only use one Audio Device at a time.

Comment: then I guess I'm going to have to use a USB splitter (one male, two female) – though such a thing even exist?

Comment: I just took a look (thank goodness for Google!) And it looks like I might have to resort to splitting the analog signal going to the headphones the old-fashioned way: looks like wire cutters and a soldering iron, alas – does seem a bit of overkill to simply allow two sets of headphones to listen to the same Hulu movie at the same time. I bet that Buffy the Vampire Slayer or Harry Dresden could do it in a moment: either put a stake in the heart of the problem or wave a hand. Maybe I have to go to Merlin…